# Firebase Crash Report Upload symbols to Crash Report Error

Tags: firebase, symbols, firebase-crash-reporting, run-script

I have created a dummy project to test Firebase Crash Reporting, I added firebase without cocoapods using the firebase documentation in [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/ios/setup#frameworks), and then following the steps to configure crash reporting provided in the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/crash/ios), but I'm having problems when I try to upload the symbols to firebase using the Run Script Phase.

```
# Replace this with the GOOGLE_APP_ID from your GoogleService-Info.plist file
GOOGLE_APP_ID=1:370179177745:ios:82b933f2b3a37fc4

# Replace the /Path/To/ServiceAccount.json with the path to the key you just downloaded
"${SRCROOT}"/CrashTest/upload-sym "${SRCROOT}/CrashTest/crashtest-3c510-firebase-crashreporting-orbso-af39436f7f.json"
```

[Project Directory and Run Script Phase "Upload symbols to Crash Report"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/flciu.png)

[Error when building application](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EWI5P.png)

I have searched for an answer in stack overflow, but haven't found the answer, I hope someone can help me, Thanks.

Comment: Yeah I also got problems with firebase, but however nobody will help you with firebase problems on stackoverflow.